# Office 2016 VBA wrong Toolbox icons size in windows 10

Tags: vba, excel, toolbox, office-2016

Not sure it this is the right place or how to describe my problem. I have a brand new windows 10 and installed Office 2016. Now when I want to develop something in VBA in Excel or Word and I add a UserForm the icons in toolbox which represent the controls to use on the form are too small. The strange thing is, when I first added a form, the toolbox windows was hardly visible (first image). Does anyone know what the problem is? Or better how to solve it.

[image: Initial toolbox]
[image: Expanded toolbox]

Comment: I am having the same issue. Have you been able to find a solution? I suspect that it has something to do with the intersection of Windows 10, high-DPI monitors, and java. I am having a similar issue with the statistical package Weka, and that seems to be the intersection there. Are you running Windows 10 on a high-dpi (4K) display?

Comment: @devW, yes. Running on a Dell XPS15 windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with SQL Management Studio. Same odd behaviour. Luckely today I stumbled upon a solution which works perfectly for SMSS. So I guess I can try it voor VBA as well.

[SMSS solution](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/10/14/ssms-in-high-dpi-displays-how-to-stop-the-madness/#comments)

This is a nice workaround, but it is not needed anymore, because MS has an updated version available for SMSS which you can find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt238290.aspx)

Anyway, I know now what the issue is, so I can try this workaround for other applications too.